# Missing WP-content.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, cyberduck

I'm working on a wordpress site on which the wordpress core, plugins and theme are all outdated which I think is the reason that certain pictures look out of place and text doesn't look the same as it used to (not sure if this is correct).

The problem is that when I try to update these from the wordpress admin dashboard I get the error "Unable to locate WordPress content directory (wp-content)." I've used cyberduck and the FTP details to look for the file myself, or the wp-config.php file, which I also haven't been able to find. However going to the website as a visitor I'm able to see everything so I feel like the content should be generated from somewhere.

What would be the solution to resolving the issue and finding the files?

Comment: I'm running WP 5.9.3

Comment: You can go to **Tools > Site Health > Info > Directories and Sizes** to know website details & issues.

Comment: You may need to verify that the FTP credentials are placing you high enough in the directory to be able to see the files and directories you want to verify. /public_html/ or /www/ are usually good targets.

I agree - if the website is loading images, a contents folder must exist. Sometimes, security plugins or installers will rename the wp-contents folder to make it harder for bad actors to attack the website. Do you think any such software was installed on your website?

Comment: It might be, I've contacted the people who ran the site before. I did try to use an FPT client to check all of the files that I was able to see, which all seemed empty so I might just not be authorised. I've also contacted the host and the provider to see if they can help me along. Thank you!

Comment: -EDIT: It doesn't seem like I've got any plugins installed that can move/rename files...